# advantages/differences of env vs printenv command in linux

Tags: linux

What are the differences between the commands "printenv" vs "env"?
What are the advantages of one vs the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find an answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284069/448694

> **Overall, `env` use cases compare with `printenv`:**
>
> 1. print environment variables, but `printenv` can do the same
> 2. Disable shell builtin but can achieve with `enable` cmd too.
> 3. set variable but pointless due to some shells already can do it without
>    `env`, e.g.
>    $ HOME=/dev HOME=/tmp USER=root /bin/bash -c "cd ~; pwd"
>    /tmp
> 4. `#!/usr/bin/env python` header, but still not portable if `env` not in /usr/bin
> 5. `env -i`, disable all env. I find it useful to figure out the critical environment variables for certain program, to make it run from `crontab`.  e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284069/448694) In interactive mode, run `declare -p > /tmp/d.sh` to stores attributes variables. [2]  In `/tmp/test.sh`, write: `. /tmp/d.sh; eog /home/xiaobai/Pictures/1.jpg` [3] Now run `env -i bash /tmp/test.sh` [4] If it success to display image, remove half of variables in `/tmp/d.sh` and run `env -i bash /tmp/test.sh` again. If something failed, undo it. Repeat the step to narrow down. [5] Finally I figure out `eog` requires `$DISPLAY` to run in `crontab`, and absent of `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` will slow down the display of image.
> 6. `target_PATH="$PATH:$(sudo printenv PATH)";` is useful to directly use the root path without having to further parse the output of `env` or `printenv`.

> e.g:
>
> xb@dnxb:~$ sudo env | grep PATH
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
> xb@dnxb:~$ sudo printenv | grep PATH
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
> xb@dnxb:~$ sudo printenv PATH
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
> xb@dnxb:~$ sudo env PATH
> env: ‘PATH’: No such file or directory
> xb@dnxb:~$